# Container View Controllers pre iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios

iOS 5 adds a nice feature allowing you to [nest UIViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81). Using this pattern it was easy for me to create a custom alert view -- I created a semi-transparent view to darken the screen and a custom view with some widgets in it that I could interact with. I added the VC as a child of the VC in which I wanted it to display, then added its views as subviews and did a little animation to bring it on the screen.

Unfortunately, I need to support iOS 4.3. Can something like this be done, or do I have to manage my "alert" directly from the VC in which I want to display it?

**MORE INFO**

So if I create a custom view in a nib whose file owner is "TapView" and who has a child view that is a UIButton. I tie the UIButton action to a IBAction in TapView.

Now in my MainControllerView I simple add the TapView:

```
TapView *tapView = [[TapView alloc] init];
[[self view] addSubview:tapView];
```

I see my TapView, but I can't interact with the UIButton on it and can interact with a UIButton on the MainControllerView hidden behind it. For some reason I am not figuring out what I'm missing...

Comment: Why does an alert view need to be a view controller? It doesn't really fit the definition of a view controller, and could just as easily be a UIView subclass, just like UIAlertView.

Comment: @jrturton I'd like to encapsulate the behavior of the view in its own controller to make it more easily portable, rather than having to implement the views interactivity in the containing VC. Could I do that with a view?

Comment: Yes, you can have anything you like inside a UIView subclass. It can respond to touches, send delegate messages and so forth.

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight and report back -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but, in situations where I've needed more control over potential several controllers, I've implemented a pattern where I have a "master" controller object (doesn't need to be descendent from UIViewController), which implements a delegate protocol (declared separately in it's own file), and then have whatever other controllers I need to hook into declare an object of that type as a delegate, and the master can do whatever it needs to do in response to messages from the controllers with the delegate, at whatever point you need; in your case, that being displaying the alert and acting as it's delegate to handle the button selection. I find this approach to be very effective, simpler and usually cleaner. YMMV ;-)

Comment: I think my main concern is that regardless of delegation that one of the two VC's I want to display simultaneously would be allowed to unload. Declaring it a child would stop that from happening, but it's not an option for 4.3.

Comment: jrturton's solution seems pretty valid, too. Not sure that you'd even need to abstract all that into a separate controller. That said, I'm not super clear on what you're trying to accomplish, either. If this new object you're talking about doesn't need to interact with the navigation, or respond to the controller life cycle methods, then just using a custom UIView sub seems simpler. Curious to see what you come up with ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Regd. your second query, where you are trying to create a custom view using nib. Don't change the FileOwner type, instead set "TapView" for the class property of the top level view object.

Once you have done this, you might experience difficulty when making connections. For that just manually choose the TapView file for making connections.

Also, to load the view you need to load its nib file. For which you can create a class level helper method in TapView class like below

```
+(TapView *) getInstance
{
    NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TapView" owner:self options:nil];

    TapView *view;
    for (id object in bundle) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[TapView class]]) {
            view = (TapView *) object;

            break;
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

Now, you get a refrence to you view object like this

```
TapView *tapView = [TapView getInstance];
```